# why would returned value of "make_share<Type>" in function list be rvalue?

Tags: c++

here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class Quote {
 public:
  Quote() = default;
  Quote(const string& book, double sales_price)    
      : bookNo(book), price(sales_price) {}
  string isbn() const { return bookNo; }

 private:
  string bookNo;
  double price = 0.0;
};

class Basket {
 public:
  void add_item(shared_ptr<Quote>& sale) { items.insert(sale); }    
  double total_receipt(ostream& s) const;

 private:
  static bool compare(const shared_ptr<Quote>& lhs,
                      const shared_ptr<Quote>& rhs) {
    return lhs->isbn() < rhs->isbn();
  }
  multiset<shared_ptr<Quote>, decltype(compare)*> items{compare};
};

int main() {
  Basket item;
  item.add_item(make_shared<Quote>("aaaa", 1));       //here is the problem is   
  return 0;
}
```

when i complier it.I got wrong message **cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::shared_ptr&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::shared_ptr’**
Then i change code to this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class Quote {
 public:
  Quote() = default;
  Quote(const string& book, double sales_price)    
      : bookNo(book), price(sales_price) {}
  string isbn() const { return bookNo; }

 private:
  string bookNo;
  double price = 0.0;
};

class Basket {
 public:
  void add_item(const shared_ptr<Quote>& sale) { items.insert(sale); }      //after debug  i add  "const" at the front of  ''shared_ptr<Quote>& sale'',it works
  double total_receipt(ostream& s) const;

 private:
  static bool compare(const shared_ptr<Quote>& lhs,
                      const shared_ptr<Quote>& rhs) {
    return lhs->isbn() < rhs->isbn();
  }
  multiset<shared_ptr<Quote>, decltype(compare)*> items{compare};
};

int main() {
  Basket item;
  item.add_item(make_shared<Quote>("aaaa", 1));       //here is the problem is   
  return 0;
}
```

It works.So that means `make_shared<Quote>("aaaa",1)`returns a rvalue type?
But i change function `main()` to this:

```
int main() {
  Basket item;
  shared_ptr<Quote> ptr = make_shared<Quote>("aaaa", 1);
  item.add_item(ptr);
  cout << endl;
}
```

and delete `const` at the front of  `shared_ptr<Quote>& sale`in function list  `void add_item( const shared_ptr<Quote>& sale) { items.insert(sale); }`.It also woks.So that means `make_shared<Quote>("aaaa",1)` returns a lvalue type.It conflicts to  mentioned before.
So can i think that when `make_shared<Quote>("aaaa",1)`in a function list ,it returns rvalue?
I also wanna know why would be this.Thanks!

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` <-- please no. This is not a standard header. Looking at your code, you're also `using namespace std;` both are bad practice. Please use the standardized headers and `std::` everything.

Comment: Also, if you don't need to use a `shared_ptr`, don't use a `shared_ptr`. In fact, there doesn't seem to be a reason you couldn't use a `std::multiset<Quote, ...> items{...};` here. You don't need double indirection. But why are you using a `multiset` at all? Why not put everything in a `std::vector`? It's more efficient. Do you need ordering all the time? Can't you just `std::sort` it when needed?

Comment: Just add an overload taking an rvalue reference? `void add_item(std::shared_ptr<Quote>& sale) { ... } void add_item(std::shared_ptr<Quote>&& sale) { items.insert(std::move(sale)); }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::make_shared` returns a `std::shared_ptr<...>`, which is not a reference type, therefore the expression `std::make_shared<...>(...)` is a *prvalue* (a subcategory of rvalues). This is true for all functions returning objects by-value, rather than by-reference.

Non-`const` lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues, as the message is telling you, while `const` lvalue references and rvalue references can.

The line

```
shared_ptr<Quote> ptr = make_shared<Quote>("aaaa", 1);
```

works, because there is a constructor of `shared_ptr<Quote>` which accepts rvalues, namely the move constructor. Since C++17 it is even simpler, since it is guaranteed that initializing a variable with a prvalue of the same type doesn't move or copy. Instead it will directly construct the return value of `std::make_shared` in `ptr`.

In the line

```
item.add_item(ptr);
```

the expression `ptr` is a lvalue. The names of variables used as expressions are *always* lvalues. And because the type of `ptr` is not `const`-qualified, a non-`const` lvalue reference can bind to it.

---

> returns a rvalue type

*rvalue* and *lvalue* are *value categories*. These are not properties of types, they are properties of expressions. I think you might be confusing them with *rvalue references* and *lvalue references*, which are qualities of types.

Answer (score 3):

> So that means make_shared("aaaa",1) returns a lvalue type.It conflicts to mentioned before.

**No**, it doesn't mean that `make_shared<Quote>("aaaa",1)` returns an lvalue type.

From [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

> `std::make_share` returns an expression whose value category is an **rvalue**.

The reason your last case works is explained below.

When you wrote:

```
shared_ptr<Quote> ptr = make_shared<Quote>("aaaa", 1); //this is initialization and uses one of shared_ptr's constructor
```

The above statement means 2 things:

1. `ptr` is an object of type `shared_ptr<Quote>`
2. The **value category** of expression `ptr` is **lvalue**.

Next, you wrote:

```
item.add_item(ptr); //this works because the expression ptr is an lvalue
```

And since we can bind a **non-const lvalue reference** to an **lvalue** there is no error in this case even if you remove the `const` from `add_item`'s parameter.